# Spring with Quartz worker initialize a member only once?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a QuartzJob with multiple methods that call the same rest API
The class holds a member (configuration ) with the  rest api configuration.
The  rest api configuration is initialize once using getConfiguration method.

```
public QuartzJob implements Job{
     @Value("${API_URL}")private String apiUrl;

     ApiCallConfiguration configuration = getConfiguration();

     method1(){call api using configuration  }
     method2(){call api using configuration  }
     method3(){call api using configuration  }
}
```

When I try to create a constructor, it fails probably because  the API values are not constructed yet...  @Value("${API_URL}")private String apiUrl;
Exception below.

what is the correct way to initialize the configuration property only once in the QuartzJob after everything is set up?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Configuration key     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Configuration key API_URL has no value
 at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notBlank(Validate.java:451)
 at com.xerox.printerTech.quartz.jobs.PrinterVerificationJob.getPrinterRestApiConfig(PrinterVerificationJob.java:722)
 at com.xerox.printerTech.quartz.jobs.PrinterVerificationJob.<init>(PrinterVerificationJob.java:164)
 ... 10 more  has no value
 at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notBlank(Validate.java:451)
 at com.xerox.printerTech.quartz.jobs.PrinterVerificationJob.getPrinterRestApiConfig(PrinterVerificationJob.java:722)
 at com.xerox.printerTech.quartz.jobs.PrinterVerificationJob.<init>(PrinterVerificationJob.java:164)
 ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue using  @Component and  @Autowired
here is a sample code:

```
public QuartzJob implements Job{

    @Autowired
    ApiCallConfiguration configuration;

     method1(){configuration.getApiUrl();  }
     method2(){configuration.apiUseSSL();  }
     method3(){configuration.getApiUserName();  }
}


@Component
public class ApiCallConfiguration {

    public ApiCallConfiguration(        
                @Value("${API_URL}")      String apiUrl,
                @Value("${API_URL_SSL}")  String apiUseSSL
                @Value("${API_USER_NAME}")  String apiUserName
               ){
                this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
                this.apiUseSSL = apiUseSSL;
                this.apiUserName = apiUserName;
                }

    }
```